# doubt on the construction of sets that respect a proposition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm a newbie in the math field, first of all sorry for my bad english, as the title say I've a doubt about a very easy exercise.
The excercise track says: 
"Build (Define or something like this) three sets (A, B, C)  for wich A ∩ (B ∪ C) ≠ (A ∩ B) ∪ C." 
I've tried to answer in this way but i don't know if it's right and I have doubts about the validity of some passages:

∃x : x ∈ A ∩ (B ∪ C) ⇔ x ∉ (A ∩ B) ∪ C →
→ x ∈ (A ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ C) ⇔ x ∉ (A ∩ B) ∪ C → 
→ if x ∈ A ∩ C ⇒ x ∉ C ⇒ x ∈ A →
→ ∀A, ∀B,∀C, ∃D : C = D/A ⇒ ∃x : x ∈ A ∩ (B ∪ C) ⇔ x ∉ (A ∩ B) ∪ C

Is this correct? if yes is this enough to answer the track?

Comment: Note, If you are just to define such a set, then you can simply give an example, such as anon's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating this a lot. You just need to write down 3 sets which fulfill these properties.

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{2,3,4\}$ and $C=\{3,4,5\}$. Then $A\cap(B\cup C)=\{2,3\}$, but $(A\cap B)\cup C=\{3\}$.